# Set "SliderTrackThemeHeight" on a slider

Tags: xaml, windows-8, controltemplate

I'm trying to style a slider in XAML. I see that the size of the thumb is controlled by a StaticResource called: "SliderTrackThemeHeight".
Only, I can't find where this is defined so I can change it? :/
I could manually type it in for now, but in future where I want to reuse a control template it'd be good to know.

Thank you geniuses!

Nick

```
<Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template for defining any double value( which is the case of height) is

< x:Double x:Key〓"customHeight"> 10 < /x:Double>

Now you can use "customHeight" instead of slidertrackthemeheight and get height as 10.